# mobile web app to detect iphone app version

Tags: javascript, iphone, objective-c, ios, html

I have a mobile web app that works in conjunction to a native app (downloaded from the app store). When I run the web app, I am detecting if the native app is installed when the user clicks on some buttons. So far so good. Now, how can I detect which VERSION of my app is installed? Is this even possible?

Comment: Maybe some frameworks that interface with the system can help you.

Comment: which system? which framework? thanks.

Comment: I do not know. I do not js much. Sorry :)

Comment: What's your code for detecting the native app?

Comment: call the URL scheme for this app and getting an error back :)